# 3d reconstruction using python and opencv with multiple images

Tags: opencv, cmake, dockerfile, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to perform 3D reconstruction from sets of images using OpenCV. Being somewhat new to openCV, I found a useful example that demonstrates the generation of a point cloud from images here:

https://github.com/alyssaq/reconstruction

Unfortunately, when I tried to run the commands which were written on the README.md file, I got the following error.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD79A.png)

As you can see the error is showing the minimum version required for the cmake is 3.5 and claims the version that is being run is 3.0.2.

But as you can see that the cmake version that I am running is 3.9.1.

I tried with removing(uninstalling) the cmake and reinstalled. But issue is still there.

The contents of the $PATH variable are as follows:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Can you add the results of your `PATH` variable? try `echo $PATH`

Comment: Edited in the results of the PATH variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect error messages and other output related to the problem to be **in the question post** itself **as text**, not linked as images. Please, paste textual content of the screenshot into the question post. You may format  with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.